# Session variable not recognized

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, dreamweaver

I am working on a PHP system that shows the schedule of students. I have a database and a table in a PHP file in Dreamweaver, all connected. However, i get stuck when i want to show the next day of the schedule. There is a table column in MySQL called 'day', with a value of 1 to 5 for monday to friday.

In the beginning of the Dreamweaver code, i added this:

```
    session_start();
       if (!isset($_SESSION["currentday"])){
           $_SESSION["currentday"] = 1;
       }
```

I added two arrows to the PHP page to go to the next or previous day. However, the database doesn't seem to recognise the session variable. Part of the query is:

```
... AND lesson.day='$currentday'
```

When I run the page, this is the result: 
**Notice: Undefined variable: currentday in E:**

Comment: Shouldn't be ... AND lesson.day='".$_SESSION['currentday']."'? Or you are assigning it somewhere else?

Comment: post the full code or atleast the part where datas or inserted and html code of it  , so that we can help. we also didnt find where you use variable `huidigedag`

Comment: Sorry, I translated the variables for better understanding, but forgot that one, it should be currentday as well.

Comment: @keepwalking of course... I was thinking too difficult... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U must first add `$currentday=$_SESSION['currentday']`